The following JS and Perl programs encrypt with the same data but produce different resut. Should they not produce the same output?
The following programs, one in Javascript, and the other in Perl, are supposed to perform the same task, they have the same input data. However, the output is different. The problem originated in the JS being used on the client side, sending a POST request to an app on the server side, written in Perl. The Perl program failed to decrypt with no obvious reason why. Analysing it I arrived to the conclusion that the libraries, in the two different programming languages, were behaving differently. So I wrote the client side in Perl to prove the point. The results are below.
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

function logBytes(description, wordArray) {
    const bytes = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(wordArray);
    console.log(description, bytes);
}

function encrypt(key32, iv16, data) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key32);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv16);
    const utf8data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data);

    // Log data and byte arrays
    console.log("Data: " + data);
    logBytes("Key Bytes:", key);
    logBytes("IV Bytes:", iv);
    logBytes("Data Bytes:", utf8data);

    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(utf8data, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    console.log("Encrypted (Base64):", encrypted.toString());
}

const data = "myemail@myserver.com";
const key32 = "9d066ab6dc74593bbcef0876b4f7c00bada3acce6134fc64fa31a2cf995a39dd";
const iv16 = "9b2b9bdb4af5357cd78a8a2257c51a7f";
encrypt(key32, iv16, data);

output:
 % node test.js
Data: myemail@myserver.com
Key Bytes: 9d066ab6dc74593bbcef0876b4f7c00bada3acce6134fc64fa31a2cf995a39dd
IV Bytes: 9b2b9bdb4af5357cd78a8a2257c51a7f
Data Bytes: 6d79656d61696c406d797365727665722e636f6d
Encrypted (Base64): iit+mjBnWsMrMkJp63hpRmsCZgIxZ4FPZQId35qv12s=

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::AES;

sub logMessage {
  my ($message) = @_;
  print "$message\n";
}

sub logBytes {
    my ($description, $bytes) = @_;
    my $hex = unpack('H*', $bytes);
    logMessage("$description: $hex");
}

sub encrypt {
    my ($key32, $iv16, $data) = @_;

    my $key = pack('H*', $key32);
    my $iv = pack('H*', $iv16);

    # Log data and byte arrays
    logMessage("Data: $data");
    logBytes("Key Bytes", $key);
    logBytes("IV Bytes", $iv);
    logBytes("Data Bytes", $data);

    my $cipher = Crypt::OpenSSL::AES->new($key);

    my $block_size = 16;
    my $padding = $block_size - (length($data) % $block_size);
    $data .= chr($padding) x $padding;

    my $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($data);

    my $encrypted_base64 = encode_base64($encrypted, "");

    logMessage("Encrypted (Base64): $encrypted_base64");
}

sub main {
  my $data = "myemail\@myserver.com";
  my $key32 = '9d066ab6dc74593bbcef0876b4f7c00bada3acce6134fc64fa31a2cf995a39dd';
  my $iv16 = '9b2b9bdb4af5357cd78a8a2257c51a7f';
  encrypt($key32, $iv16, $data);
}

main();
exit (0);

output
% ./test.pm  
Data: myemail@myserver.com
Key Bytes: 9d066ab6dc74593bbcef0876b4f7c00bada3acce6134fc64fa31a2cf995a39dd
IV Bytes: 9b2b9bdb4af5357cd78a8a2257c51a7f
Data Bytes: 6d79656d61696c406d797365727665722e636f6d
Encrypted (Base64): rk7JgOwsb7atyvEIXVNQkexbx5SYzufE05LZAoqtZGk=

Versions:

Perl:
Crypt::OpenSSL::AES version: 0.19
MIME::Base64 version: 3.16

JS:
crypto-js@4.2.0


In the Perl code the ECB mode is used, whereas in the CryptoJS code the CBC mode is used.

See Crypt::OpenSSL::AES, 2nd parmater of new(). Note that padding can be configured so that your custom padding is not required.

Changed encode_base64($encrypted) to encode_base64($encrypted, "") to avoid adding the LF in the first place.

Thank you @Topaco - changing JS CryptoJS.AES.encrypt to CryptoJS.AES.encrypt fixed the problem - thank you. I wonder if the mode parameter to the same call needs changing too. I did not change it and my test now passes.

Unfortunately, I can't make sense of your description and it's not clear to me what you did. The posted codes are incompatible because of the different modes. To make both compatible, you have to change the mode in the Perl script to CBC (see link above) or in the JavaScript to ECB (the latter would be the worse solution, as ECB is insecure).

Regarding the Perl script on the decrypting server side, I can only guess since you haven't posted that code. If it is compatible with the posted Perl script for the client side, it means that the (insecure) ECB mode is used and you have to change the mode in the JavaScript to ECB for compatibility. But this is speculation on my part until you have posted the decryption code.

@Topaco sorry for the confusion, ignore previous comment.

Problem solved with thanks to @Topaco who provided the clue - credits to him.
The following client side JS and server side Perl are a solution
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

function encrypt(key_hex, iv_hex, data) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key_hex);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv_hex);
    const utf8data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data);

    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(utf8data, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    // Convert to base64 for easier transmission and compatibility with Perl's decode_base64
    return encrypted.toString();
}

var key_hex = "9d066ab6dc74593bbcef0876b4f7c00bada3acce6134fc64fa31a2cf995a39dd";
var iv_hex  = "9b2b9bdb4af5357cd78a8a2257c51a7f";
var data    = process.argv[2];
const encryptedBase64 = encrypt(key_hex, iv_hex, data);
console.log(encryptedBase64);

use MIME::Base64;
use Crypt::CBC;

use strict;

sub decrypt_hex {
  my ($key_hex, $iv_hex, $data) = @_;
 
  # Convert hex key and IV to binary
  my $key = pack("H*", $key_hex);
  my $iv = pack("H*", $iv_hex);

  # Set up the decryption cipher with CBC mode and Rijndael (AES)
  my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
        -key    => $key,
        -cipher => 'Crypt::Rijndael',
        -iv     => $iv,
        -header => 'none',
        -keysize => 32,  # Adjust according to your key length (16 for AES-128, 24 for AES-192, 32 for AES-256)
        -literal_key => 1,
        -padding => 'standard'  # Ensures PKCS#7 padding is handled
  );

  # Decode the base64-encoded data
  my $encrypted = decode_base64($data);

  # Decrypt the data
  my $decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);

  return $decrypted;
}

